# @media rule adds extra space to my page

Tags: html, css

I added `@media screen and (max-width: 1000px)` rule to my code with modifications it would make. I wanted to make boxes stack up on `width: 1000px;` and I did succeed to do that, however, now when the boxes stack up, there is an extra space to the right of my webpage.

It appears that my boxes somehow conflict with one of the lines of the header style. Tried removing margins and did not pay off. I want that space removed that those boxes add.

Also, it is possible that the header does not have to do anything here and only the boxes are stretching out the website.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #262626;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header h1 {
  line-height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.subcontent div a {
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 2px solid #3B3B3B;
  font-family: "ALK Rounded Mtav Med", sans-serif;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.subcontent div {
  display: table;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .subcontent {
    display: block;
  }
  .subcontent div {
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>ვისწავლოთ</h1>
      <h1>იაპონური</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div>
        <a href="#">ანბანი</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">გრამატიკა</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div>
        <a href="#">ლექსიკონი</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">დიალოგები</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change `display:flex` to `display:block`. Instead you can simply change flex-diretion to column and make `width:auto` to avoid the overflow due to the margin added to the `width:100%`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #262626;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header h1 {
  line-height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.subcontent div a {
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 2px solid #3B3B3B;
  font-family: "ALK Rounded Mtav Med", sans-serif;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.subcontent div {
  display: table;
  margin: 15px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.subcontent {
  flex-direction:column;
}
  .subcontent div {
    height: 300px;
    width:auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>ვისწავლოთ</h1>
      <h1>იაპონური</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div>
        <a href="#">ანბანი</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">გრამატიკა</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div>
        <a href="#">ლექსიკონი</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">დიალოგები</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: After I personally tried the code, `flex-basis: 100%;` line is diving the two of my containers with the other two and adds space between them. I removed the line because I did not want that. Could you anyway tell me what did you write that line for?

Comment: @LeqsoBezarashvili oh, it's usless, you can remove it :) initially I was trying something else so I didn't remove it. Column direction and with:auto is all what you need ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `margin: 15px` on the `.subcontent` which makes a margin of 15px all around the `.subcontent`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #262626;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header h1 {
  line-height: 50%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.subcontent div a {
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  border: 2px solid #3B3B3B;
  font-family: "ALK Rounded Mtav Med", sans-serif;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.subcontent div {
  display: table;
  /* margin: 15px; This is the villain */
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .subcontent {
    display: block;
  }
  .subcontent div {
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>ვისწავლოთ</h1>
      <h1>იაპონური</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div>
        <a href="#">ანბანი</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">გრამატიკა</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div>
        <a href="#">ლექსიკონი</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#">დიალოგები</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/kot4kt3j/)

Comment: Felt like it was overkill to add the entire snippet, just for a single line - added now though.